# GLmol (webGL) input file parsing Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdb

GLmol - Molecular Viewer on WebGL/Javascript: http://webglmol.sourceforge.jp/index-en.html

Example: http://www.macinchem.org/reviews/jsmol/jsmol.php

Basing on the example, I wrote this code:

In controllers.js:

```
$http.get('/img/1bheA.pdb').
    then(function (res) {
        var str = String(res.data)
        $scope.glmol02 = new GLmol(str);
     });
```

Where the file is a simple PDB file, and the GLmol input is effectively a string (checked with typeof).

The html div where I use GLmol is

```
<div id="{{glmol02}}" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: black;"></div>
```

The Error is:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression
```

Do you have any idea of what's happening here? Please ask me if you need more details.

Thank you in advance.